# How to use string functions while passing parameter values

Tags: sql-server

How can I use function while passing parameters?

for example, want to use LEFT() function while passing parameter value to my stored procedure

like below:

**Doesn't work when use any function directly as below:**

```
EXEC [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] @MyStringParameter = LEFT('ABCDEF',3);
```

**Works if use variable as below:**

```
DECLARE @MyStr VARCHAR(3)=LEFT('ABCDEF',3);
EXEC [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] @MyStringParameter = @MyStr;
```

In my case, I have list of parameters and don't want to declare every single variable one by one. kindly tell me if any way to use functions/udf instead declare variable.

Comment: Using an equals sign is not the same as passing parameters...Or have I missed something? Post your SP code perhaps

Comment: You can only pass constants or variables as parameters, not expressions.

Comment: @Grantly thanks for suggest, the sample code is mentioned in question. actual code will not help here.